# How do I remove documents using Node.js Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, authentication

```
FBFriendModel.find({
    id: 333
}, function (err, docs) {
    docs.remove(); //Remove all the documents that match!
});
```

The above doesn't seem to work. The records are still there.

Can someone fix?

Answer (score 556):

If you don't feel like iterating, try

```
FBFriendModel.find({ id:333 }).remove( callback );
```

or

```
FBFriendModel.find({ id:333 }).remove().exec();
```

`mongoose.model.find` returns a [Query](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js), which has a [`remove` function](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-remove).

**Update for Mongoose v5.5.3 - `remove()` is now deprecated.** Use `deleteOne()`, `deleteMany()` or `findOneAndDelete() instead.`

Comment: Does this run pre/post-remove middleware? (some model methods bypass document middleware and I'm not sure if this is one of them, the docs are unclear)

Comment: I suppose @hunterloftis has figured this out already, but for anyone else reading the answer is no, this will not run pre/post middleware on individual docs.

Comment: This seems many of the other answers mention `.exec()` however this doesn't at all. Is `.exec()` needed, are there side effects to using it or not?

Comment: The docs are clear (maybe they've been updated) that this bypasses middleware - see the bottom of http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html - so be careful, using this method can cause serious, hard to track down issues.

Comment: @DanH `.exec()` does an unsafe write and no callback is required for execution of removal. I'd stick with the callback, it's safer and you know what happened when something goes wrong, not to mention race condition problems.

Comment: great answer! what are the arguments of the callback?

Comment: If you click on "show code" you'll it calls the callback thusly: process.nextTick(callback.bind(null, err));

Comment: is `exec()` necessary?

Comment: this is nice, but what if I need to access the docs before/after removing them?
    FBFriendModel.find({ id:333 }).remove().exec(function(err, docs)
    {
         console.log(docs); // empty
    });

Comment: Asked that question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662783/mongoose-find-and-remove.

Comment: @numbers1311407, you are correct that these methods bypass middleware, but what would be the right way to remove AND call middleware? I am trying to remove referenced documents in the .pre('remove')

Comment: remove().exec() -> deleteMany()

Answer (score 319):

**UPDATE: Mongoose version (5.5.3)**

remove() is deprecated and you can use deleteOne(), deleteMany(), or bulkWrite() instead.

As of `"mongoose": ">=2.7.1"` you can remove the document directly with the `.remove()` method rather than finding the document and then removing it which seems to me more efficient and easy to maintain.

See example:

```
Model.remove({ _id: req.body.id }, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
            message.type = 'notification!';
    }
    else {
            message.type = 'error';
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

As of mongoose `3.8.1`, there are several methods that lets you remove directly a document, say:

- `remove`
- `findByIdAndRemove`
- `findOneAndRemove`

Refer to [mongoose API docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html) for further information.

Comment: As noted in other comments to other answers, this bypasses middleware that is defined on the schema, and can be really dangerous. So only use it if you understand the impact that will have. For more info, see http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Comment: Just for the record, until now I always have used them without any side effects, sure, I hadn't to use any middleware in my projects :)

Comment: `remove(query)` could potentially empty *your entire collection* if you accidentally pass `query = {}`. For that reason I prefer `findOneAndRemove(query)` if I am only removing *one* document.

Comment: Also note that this is not returning a query, so neither a promise. You **can't** do `Model.remove({ _id: 'whatever' }).exec().then(...)`

Answer (score 54):

`docs` is an array of documents. so it doesn't have a `mongooseModel.remove()` method.

You can iterate and remove each document in the array separately.

Or - since it looks like you are finding the documents by a (probably) unique id - use `findOne` instead of `find`.

Comment: Seeing as this answer assumes a rather old version of mongoose, I really wouldn't object to someone changing the accepted answer.

Comment: This is actually one of the best ways to do it because it correctly invokes middleware defined on the schema - see http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html. You should only use the other methods if you're NOT using middleware in your application, and then with caution.

Answer (score 50):

This for me is the best as of version 3.8.1:

```
MyModel.findOneAndRemove({field: 'newValue'}, function(err){...});
```

And it requires only one DB call. 
Use this given that you don't perform any `remove` actions pior to the search and removal.

Comment: As long as you don't need to perform `pre 'remove'` actions it works fine.

Answer (score 45):

`remove()` has been deprecated. Use `deleteOne()`, `deleteMany()` or `bulkWrite()`.

The code I use

```
TeleBot.deleteMany({chatID: chatID}, function (err, _) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err);
                }
            });
```

Comment: This answer honestly needs more upvotes.  It's unfairly placed at the bottom of the barrel (because it hasn't been getting a half-decade of antiquated votes), but is the only answer that solves the issue of: `(node:9132) DeprecationWarning: collection.remove is deprecated. Use deleteOne, deleteMany, or bulkWrite instead.`

Answer (score 31):

Simply do

```
FBFriendModel.remove().exec();
```

Comment: Does this return a Promise? If so, what object is defined when the Promise is resolved?

Comment: @KennyWorden an effective approach to find the answer -> http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html then search for what you want but prepend '#' to the in-page search with your browser such as search on '#save' and you'll see it returns a promise.

Comment: This is kind of a dangerous answer without putting the condition the op specified in the remove...

Answer (score 30):

`mongoose.model.find()` returns a [Query Object](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-remove) which also has a `remove()` function.

You can use `mongoose.model.findOne()` as well, if you want to remove only one unique document.

Else you can follow traditional approach as well where you first retrieving the document and then remove.

```
yourModelObj.findById(id, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
        // handle error
    }

    doc.remove(callback); //Removes the document
})
```

Following are the ways on `model` object you can do any of the following to remove document(s):

```
yourModelObj.findOneAndRemove(conditions, options, callback)
```

`yourModelObj.findByIdAndRemove(id, options, callback)`

`yourModelObj.remove(conditions, callback);`

```
var query = Comment.remove({ _id: id });
query.exec();
```

Answer (score 21):

To generalize you can use:

```
SomeModel.find( $where, function(err,docs){
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  if (!docs || !Array.isArray(docs) || docs.length === 0) 
    return console.log('no docs found');
  docs.forEach( function (doc) {
    doc.remove();
  });
});
```

Another way to achieve this is:

```
SomeModel.collection.remove( function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // collection is now empty but not deleted
});
```

Answer (score 19):

**Be careful with findOne and remove!**

```
  User.findOne({name: 'Alice'}).remove().exec();
```

The code above **removes ALL** users named 'Alice' instead of **the first one** only.

*By the way, I prefer to remove documents like this:*

```
  User.remove({...}).exec();
```

*Or provide a callback and omit the exec()*

```
  User.remove({...}, callback);
```

Answer (score 15):

```
model.remove({title:'danish'}, function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
});
```

Ref: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.remove

Answer (score 14):

If you are looking for only one object to be removed, you can use

```
Person.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function (error, person){
        console.log("This object will get deleted " + person);
        person.remove();

    });
```

In this example, Mongoose will delete based on matching req.params.id.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Your answer is a duplicate of multiple answers in this thread.  Also, you should always check for error in your callbacks.

Answer (score 9):

`.remove()` works like `.find()`:

```
MyModel.remove({search: criteria}, function() {
    // removed.
});
```

Answer (score 9):

I prefer the promise notation, where you need e.g.

```
Model.findOneAndRemove({_id:id})
    .then( doc => .... )
```

Answer (score 7):

For removing document, I prefer using `Model.remove(conditions, [callback])`

Please refer API documentation for remove :-

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.remove

For this case, code will be:-

```
FBFriendModel.remove({ id : 333 }, function(err, callback){
console.log(‘Do Stuff’);
})
```

If you want to remove documents without waiting for a response from MongoDB, do not pass a callback, then you need to  call exec on the returned Query

```
var removeQuery = FBFriendModel.remove({id : 333 });
removeQuery.exec();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just use the query directly within the remove function, so:

```
FBFriendModel.remove({ id: 333}, function(err){});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can always use Mongoose built-in function:

```
var id = req.params.friendId; //here you pass the id
    FBFriendModel
   .findByIdAndRemove(id)
   .exec()
   .then(function(doc) {
       return doc;
    }).catch(function(error) {
       throw error;
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Update: `.remove()` is depreciated but this still works for older versions

```
YourSchema.remove({
    foo: req.params.foo
}, function(err, _) {
    if (err) return res.send(err)
    res.json({
        message: `deleted ${ req.params.foo }`
    })
});
```

Comment: Model.remove is deprecated

Answer (score 4):

I really like this pattern in [async/await capable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler) Express/Mongoose apps:

```js
app.delete('/:idToDelete', asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const deletedItem = await YourModel
    .findByIdAndDelete(req.params.idToDelete) // This method is the nice method for deleting
    .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err.message))

  res.status(200).send(deletedItem)
}))
```

Answer (score 2):

using remove() method you can able to remove.

```
getLogout(data){
        return this.sessionModel
        .remove({session_id: data.sid})
        .exec()
        .then(data =>{
            return "signup successfully"
        })
    }
```

Comment: Model.remove is deprecated

Comment: Maxwell s.c, make an edit request then, and correct. I know you're new to SO, but it's way more helpful to fix it than to comment that it's depreciated. Maybe you could suggest an edit next time, or make an edit yourself, and take a little ownership of the situation...

Answer (score 2):

As per Samyak Jain's Answer, i use Async Await

```
let isDelete = await MODEL_NAME.deleteMany({_id:'YOUR_ID', name:'YOUR_NAME'});
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, just try this:

```
const id = req.params.id;
      YourSchema
      .remove({_id: id})
      .exec()
      .then(result => {
        res.status(200).json({
          message: 'deleted',
          request: {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/yourroutes/'
          }
        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
          error: err
        })
      });
```

Comment: `Model.remove` is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

To delete a single document you can use deleteOne() or remove()with single:true and deleteMany() or remove() to delete multiple documents :-

1. Using deleteOne()

```
    syntax
    Model.deleteOne({conditions},function(err){});

    Example
     Model.deleteOne({title:"hi"},function(err){
        if(err)
        {
            res.send(err);
        }
        else{
            res.send("deleted");
        }
    });
```

2.Using remove()

```
    syntax
    Model.remove({conditions},{single:true},function(err){});

    Example
     Model.remove({title:"hi"},{single:true},function(err){
        if(err)
        {
            res.send(err);
        }
        else{
            res.send("deleted");
        }
    });
```

3.using deleteMany()

```
syntax
Model.deleteMany({conditions},function(err){});

    Example
     Model.deleteMany({title:"hi"},function(err){
        if(err)
        {
            res.send(err);
        }
        else{
            res.send("deleted");
        }
    });
```

4. Using remove()

```
 syntax
    Model.remove({conditions},function(err){});

    Example
     Model.remove({title:"hi"},function(err){
        if(err)
        {
            res.send(err);
        }
        else{
            res.send("deleted");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

if you know `_id` of the document you can use `findByIdAndDelete(id)` and this is is a shorthand for `findOneAndDelete({ _id: id })`.

```
import Question from '../models/Question';

const deleteQuestion = (questionId: string) => {
    try {
        Question.findByIdAndDelete(questionId);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
};
```

here `questionId` is documentId (`_id`)

Answer (score -2):

```
db.collection.remove(<query>,
 {
  justOne: <boolean>,
  writeConcern: <document>
})
```

Comment: @M.R.: How can it be link-only when there is no link in the answer?? Also check: [Low quality posts and code only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345719/low-quality-posts-and-code-only-answers)

Comment: Sry misclick. But still is a low quality.