# How do I remove a document from a collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm amazed that I can't seem to find a straight answer for this. I SIMPLY want to delete a document from a collection (like deleting a record from a table in mysql). Here is what I have tried:

```
People.find(
    {key: req.params.key},
    function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        }
        if (data) {
            data.remove(callback);
        }
    });

function callback() {
    // do something
}
```

I keep getting this error in the console: "TypeError: Object  has no method 'remove'". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809788/how-do-i-remove-documents-using-node-js-mongoose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should work for you:

```
People.remove({ key:req.params.key}, function (err) {});
```

Or this:

```
var query = People.remove({ key:req.params.key });
query.exec();
```

And there are a few other ways to approach this depending upon the nature of your data (is the key unique, do you just want to remove the first one you find, etc).