# Mongoose cascading deletes in same model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is different than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348516/cascade-style-delete-in-mongoose) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881404/mongoose-model-removecallback-doesnt-remove-anything-from-my-collection).  But they are very helpful.

Basically, I have a Topic schema.  If one Topic get's deleted, I want to delete other topics.  Think of a graph where deleting a node means deleting the edges.

```
var schema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
  srcId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, validate: [edgeValidator, 'Set both srcId and destId, or neither'] },
  destId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
});
```

I want the 2nd mongo delete to run in the `schema.pre('remove', ...)`

But I don't have a model at this point.  So calling .find() or .remove() doesn't work.  What's the best way?

```
schema.pre('remove', function(next) {
  var query = '';
  var self = this;
  if (this.isEdge) {
    query = 'MATCH ()-[r:CONNECTION { mongoId: {_id} }]-() DELETE r;';
  } else {
    query = 'MATCH (n:Topic { mongoId: {_id} })-[r]-() DELETE n,r;'; 
  }
  // This is another database.   
  neo.query(query, this, function(err, data) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    if (self.isEdge) {
      return next();
    } else {
      // Now we're back to mongoose and mongodb
      // Find and remove edges from mongo
      schema.find({ mongoId: {      // <------ .find() is undefined
        $or: [
          { srcId: self._id },
          { destId: self._id }
        ]
      }}, function(err, edges) {
        edges.remove(next);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be pretty easy.

```
var Model = null;

var schema = ...

module.exports = Model = mongoose.model('Topic', schema);
```

Then just use Model in the pre-remove.  Piece of pie.