# Mongoose Find and Remove

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I'm trying to delete multiple documents that satisfy a query. However I need the data of those documents for storing them in a separate collection for undo functionality. The only way I got this to work is with multiple queries:

```
Data.find(query).exec(function(err, data)
{
    Data.remove(query).exec(function(err2)
    {
        ActionCtrl.saveRemove(data);
    });
});
```

Is there a better way? In this post: [How do I remove documents using Node.js Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809788/how-do-i-remove-documents-using-node-js-mongoose) it was suggested to use find().remove().exec():

```
Data.find(query).remove().exec(function(err, data)
{
    ActionCtrl.saveRemove(data);
});
```

However `data` is usually `1`, don't ask me why. Can I do this without infinitely nesting my queries? Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity why not use a document property to indicate if it's been "deleted"?

Comment: Partly: http://richarddingwall.name/2009/11/20/the-trouble-with-soft-delete/
Also: 1 delete command might trigger removal of several connected documents, and i want those to be restored as well if the command is undone. im using a modified memento pattern that works for multiple documents for this.

Comment: You could use Mongoose's [discriminators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.discriminator) instead. It allows two document schemas (inherited from a common base schema) to be stored in the same collection.

Answer (score 3):

As you have noted, using the following will not return the document:

```
Data.find(query).remove().exec(function(err, data) {
  // data will equal the number of docs removed, not the document itself
}
```

As such, you can't save the document in `ActionCtrl` using this approach.

You can achieve the same result using your original approach, or use some form of iteration. A control flow library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) might come in handy to handle the async calls. It won't reduce your code, but will reduce the queries. See example:

```
Data.find(query, function(err, data) {
  async.each(data, function(dataItem, callback) {
    dataItem.remove(function(err, result) {
      ActionCtrl.saveRemove(result, callback);
    });
  });
});
```

This answer assumes that the `ActionCtrl.saveRemove()` implementation can take an individual doc as a parameter, and can execute the callback from the `async.each` loop. [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback) requires a callback to be run without arguments at the end of each iteration, so you would ideally run this at the end of `.saveRemove()`

Note that the `remove` method on an individual document will actually return the document that has been removed.

Comment: Would doing the first approach return an error if the `find(query)` returns an empty array? Or would `data` indicate that nothing has been deleted?