# Keystonejs How to remove multiple document from collection?

Tags: mongoose, keystonejs

I am new to keystonejs. My question is very generic. How to remove multiple documents from Collection.

tried `keystone.list('students').find({'class':'id'}).remove().exec()` but its not working. How suppose I shoud do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try remove directly.

```
  keystone.list('students').remove({'class':'id'}, function(err){
     if(err) throw err;
```

});

I home you would have visited [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809788/how-do-i-remove-documents-using-node-js-mongoose). Or probably, this question is duplicate of it.