# Mongoose does not remove all documents from collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose Model, I try to remove all documents from a collection but after I run the code, the collection remains unmodified. Please see the code below:

```
    return ProcessedStats.remove({}).then(function (d) {
        console.log(d);
        return ProcessedStats.find({}).count().then(function(c) {
            console.log(c);
        });
    }).then(function() {
        db.disconnect();
    });
```

I call remove with an empty object, so to remove all documents, when I call find, I still have the count to 16000 documents.

What could be wrong?

Weird: if I do

```
find({})
```

and prin out data.length it equals 0, but if I do

```
.find({}).count()
```

it will equal 16000. What is wrong with the behaviour? What am I missing?

I think it was a caching issue, after I restarted the server, the count was ok

Comment: Does [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809788/how-do-i-remove-documents-using-node-js-mongoose) help ?

Comment: Please check my updated answer