# mongoose finds but doesn't remove

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am finding any document that matches my condition and I want to remove those docs.

```
MyModle.find({writer: req.body.id}, function(err, docs){
                if (err){ return console.log(err)}
                if (!docs || !Array.isArray(docs) || docs.length === 0){
                    return console.log('no docs found')}
                docs.forEach( function (doc) {
                    doc.remove();
                    console.log("Removed book with ID ",doc._id, "by writer ", req.body.id);
                });
            });
```

My console is printing the message as if the document was removed, but it is still in the collection.
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation for `remove`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-remove), the deletion is performed only if you either:

- pass a callback function: `doc.remove(function() { console.log('removed!'); });`
- or call `exec`: `doc.remove().exec()`

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5809788/7954580)

---

To fix your code, you can replace:

```
doc.remove();
console.log("Removed book with ID ",doc._id, "by writer ", req.body.id)
```

with

```
doc.remove(function() {
    console.log("Removed book with ID ",doc._id, "by writer ", req.body.id)
});
```

Comment: which part of my code in the example should I modify to get this? could you please help?

Comment: i tried your solution but still they are in the collection. what is missing here?

Comment: @cplus Have you tried printing the error?  `doc.remove(function(err) { console.log(err) })`