# How to expire/delete Mongoose document (as expected after either 5 seconds or a day)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, mongoose

Here's a simple Schema how do I delete the document after either a day or 5 seconds?

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: {type: String, required: true},//yelp id
    userId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true}
});
```

Ideas I've tried some delete after a minute nothing deletes in a day.

```
// schema.index({createdAt: 1},{expireAfterSeconds: 3600});// doesnt work
// schema.index({"expires": 1}, {expireAfterSeconds: 5});
// schema.index({ first: 1, last: -1});
 // schema.index({ createdAt: { type: Date, expires: 1 }});
 // schema.createIndex( { "lastModifiedDate": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 })
// schema.createIndex({"expire_at": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 } )
```

I'm hoping for a short sweet mongoose solution nothing too complicated.

Comment: Did you tryed this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809788/how-do-i-remove-documents-using-node-js-mongoose#answer-10266789

Comment: It has to be deleted after a certain amount of time I've spent hours looking through questions haven't found an answer that works because usually it just deletes around one minute.

Comment: Document does not need to be deleted if you don't tell him to. 
you have to separate your question to 2 parts, one is to fire a function every X minutes/hours/days, and second part, is to delete the document.for now you know how to do the second part. implementation of the first part is depends on how your application work.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to convey, can you write down what you're talking about?

Comment: Do you want to setup a time to live on a per document basis or on a per collection basis (for all documents in a collection the same TTL)?

Comment: @kentor At a per document basis.  Basically, I want to delete the document after 24 hours or by 2 am Eastern Time.

Comment: Have you seen this?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14597622/5774004

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work it removes the document around 1 minute even if you set the expire longer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TTL index to delete data automatically after 5 seconds.

db.eventlog.createIndex( { "lastModifiedDate": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 5 } )

Comment: Ok but I need to do this in node not mongoshell and explain specifically what db and eventlog are here for instance is db= mongoose and eventlog= collection('name')??  I'm going to run my database on either localhost or mongolab