# How to remove a Mongoose document if I have an instance of it already?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am not sure if I am doing this naively or not, but I suspect that there's a more efficient and clever way of handling this situation.

Let's say I have an instance of a document that I then need to remove from MongoDB following some logic checks:

```
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.postId);
    // Check whether the logged user owns this post
    if (post._userId.equals(req.user._id)) {
      await Post.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.postId);
```

Is there a way to avoid retrieving the same document twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All models have a `remove` so simply call `await post.remove()`.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/api.html#model_Model-remove

---

Edit 2024-03-07: Updated link to reflect documentation at the time of question.

Comment: The link is broken (March 2024, mongoose 8.x)

Comment: @it-alien Fixed link, do you know what the modern approach is? I don't do JS development anymore so I'm out of the loop.

Comment: afaik, now it's called deleteOne: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.deleteOne()

Answer (score 0):

Reference to one of the solution of the below post . `remove` is now deprecated.
Use `deleteOne()` `deleteMany()` `fineOneAndDelete()` instead.
[How do I remove documents using Node.js Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809788/how-do-i-remove-documents-using-node-js-mongoose)