# error TS2339: Property 'remove' does not exist on type 'Document<unknown,

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose

I'm getting this error on my application

runtime Error :

**TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/controllers/notes.ts:134:20 - error TS2339: Property 'remove' does not exist on type 'Document<unknown, {}, { createdAt: NativeDate; updatedAt: NativeDate; } & { title: string; text?: string | undefined; }> & Omit<{ createdAt: NativeDate; updatedAt: NativeDate; } & { ...; } & { ...; }, never>'.**

134         await note.remove()

highlighted Error :

**any
Property 'remove' does not exist on type 'Document<unknown, {}, { createdAt: NativeDate; updatedAt: NativeDate; } & { title: string; text?: string | undefined; }> & Omit<{ createdAt: NativeDate; updatedAt: NativeDate; } & { ...; } & { ...; }, never>'.ts(2339)**

Controllers/notes

```
import NoteModel from "../models/note";
import {RequestHandler} from 'express';
import createHttpErrors from "http-errors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export const deleteNote: RequestHandler = async (req, res, next) => {
    const noteId = req.params.noteId;

    try{

        if(!mongoose.isValidObjectId(noteId)){
            throw createHttpErrors(400, "invalid Note ID")
        }

        const note = await NoteModel.findById(noteId).exec();

        if(!note){
            throw createHttpErrors(404, "Note not found")
        }

        await note.remove();

        res.sendStatus(204)
    }
    catch(error){
       next(error)
    }
}
```

model/notes

```
import { InferSchemaType, model, Schema } from "mongoose";


const noteSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true},
    text: { type: String},
}, {timestamps: true})

type Note = InferSchemaType<typeof noteSchema>


export default model<Note>("Note",noteSchema)
```

router/notes

```
import express from 'express';
import * as NoteController from '../controllers/notes'
const router = express.Router()

router.delete('/:noteId', NoteController.deleteNote);
```

Comment: `remove` is deprecated; use `findByIdAndDelete` and the like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guessing you are following the same tutorial.

If you want to keep:

```
if (!note) {
  throw createHttpErrors(404, "Note not found")
}
```

Then use

```
await note.deleteOne()
```

`remove()` can no longer be used (src: [How do I remove documents using Node.js Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809788/how-do-i-remove-documents-using-node-js-mongoose))